# How do I connect Crystal reports to multiple database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Currently I have 3 servers with different locations. Each of the databases is having the different database name but same Table name. How do I connect to the database dynamically based on the option that I select from a dropdown list?

I tried to use setLogonInfo function but this only applicable to 1 database only without any problem. As I provided the Database name, Server name, username and password.

```
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "user";
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "pass";

            TableLogOnInfos infos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            infos.Add(logOnInfo);
            CrystalReportViewer.LogOnInfo = infos;
```

I would like a code that able to change the ServerName and DatabaseName dynamically without I need to type/choose again.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to follow the steps below:

a) Load the Report document

```
ReportDocument crReport = new ReportDocument();
crReport.Load("path and filename");
```

b) Create a Report connection information object

```
ConnectionInfo crConn = new ConnectionInfo();
crConn.ServerName = "my db server name";
crConn.DatabaseName = "my database name";
crConn.UserID = "db user name";
crConn.Password = "db password";
```

c) Apply the Logon information to each report table

```
Tables tblsReport = crReport.Database.Tables;
for(int i=0; i<tblsreport.count;i++)>
{
   Table tblReport = tblsReport[i];
   TableLogOnInfo tliTable = tblReport.LogOnInfo;
   tliTable.ConnectionInfo = crConn;
   tblReport.ApplyLogOnInfo(tliTable);
}
```

The solution was extracted from this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1074471/How-do-I-connect-Crystal-reports-to-multiple-datab).

Comment: I don't need to provide 2 more db server name and database name? Just only input 1 name?